# okhttp3.MultipartBody.Builder error package MultipartBody does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gradle

GM/GA/GE to all

I'm having a delimma here on upgrading the okhttp.MultipartBuilder to okhttp3.MultipartBody.Builder,

the original code

```
    public Content postForm(String url, Headers hdrs, ConsumerWithErr<MultipartBuilder> form)throws Exception {
        MultipartBuilder mp=new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);
        form.accept(mp);
```

So I have to update it like this,

```
    public Content postForm(String url, Headers hdrs, ConsumerWithErr<MultipartBody.Builder> form)throws Exception {
        MultipartBody.Builder mp=new MultipartBody.Builder().type(MultipartBody.Builder.FORM);
        form.accept(mp)
```

But got error,

```
error: package MultipartBody does not exist
    public Content postForm(String url, Headers hdrs, ConsumerWithErr<MultipartBody.Builder> form)throws Exception {
```

What should be the problem here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do this,

```
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody.Builder;
```

and,

```
    public Content postForm(String url, Headers hdrs, ConsumerWithErr<MultipartBody.Builder> form)throws Exception {
        MultipartBody.Builder mp=new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
        form.accept(mp);
```